# MemCache requires PHP memcache extension to be loaded

Tags: php, yii, memcached

Memcache error on yii migrate.

> exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'MemCache
>   requires PHP memcache extension to be loaded.'
>
> in /Applications/AMPPS/www/G2G/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/caching/MemCache.php:220
>
> Stack trace:
>       #0 /Applications/AMPPS/www/G2G/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/caching/MemCache.php(116):
>   yii\caching\MemCache->getMemcache()

I have memcached installed on my laptop and in my php its active as well. But still getting above error. Any reason to this?

**Config**

```
 'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\MemCache',
        'servers' => [
            [
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 11211
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Beware of the subtle difference between memcache and memcache**d**. You may need to configure that library to use memcached and not memcache

Comment: @apokryfos It was working few days back. I am getting this error today only.

Comment: Show config of your cache component.

Comment: @rob006 I have updated my question

Comment: any fix with this issue?

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed memcache**d**, you need to configure your component to use it:

```
'cache' => [
    'class' => 'yii\caching\MemCache',
    'useMemcached' => true,
    'servers' => [
        [
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => 11211
        ],
    ],
],
```

[`MemCache::$useMemcached` documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-caching-memcache#$useMemcached-detail):

> Whether to use memcached or memcache as the underlying caching extension. If true, [memcached](http://pecl.php.net/package/memcached) will be used. If false, [memcache](http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache) will be used. Defaults to false.

Comment: I have tried this solution. Still received the same error.

Comment: Then you probably don't have memcached installed. If you have multiple PHP versions installed, make sure that you're using correct one with correct config.

Comment: I do have memcached. I just restarted my service. 
brew services restart memcached
`Stopping `memcached`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `memcached` (label: homebrew.mxcl.memcached)
==> Successfully started `memcached` (label: homebrew.mxcl.memcached)`

Comment: Memcache server and memcached PHP extensions are two different things.

Comment: `extension=memcache.so` I have extension as well. Which other memcached do i need?

Answer (score -4):

```
 'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
    ],
```

Comment: Welcome Suco. Please provide some sort of explanation to your answer.